# Import public certificate to Azure Website

Tags: azure, certificate

We need to use in our Azure Website a public certificate (.cer) from a 3rd party so we encrypt a message which they would decrypt with their private key.

It seems this is only supported for Cloud Services: from portal go to Cloud Services->Pick Cloud Service->Certificates->Upload. Message is: Upload a certificate file (.pfx or .cer).

For Azure Websites this option is not available: from portal go to Websites->Pick Website->Configure->Upload a certificate, then the message is: Upload a certificate file (.pfx) for use in your website. No .cer option and it also asks for the password.

Is there any way we can upload a certificate so our Azure website can use in the same manner we do on-premise by taking the public certificate from the certificate store?

Answer (score -1):

From your on premise website export the certificate with all path and enable export features. You will be asked to provide a password and location on disk. Use this pfx for Azure. ;)

Comment: Being a public certificate from a 3rd party, this certificate does not have a private key. So when I try to export it, PFX is disabled, only DER (encoded binary X.509), Base-64 encoded X.509 and PKCS#7 are enabled. PKCS#12 is disabled.